# Undefined offset: 2

Tags: functions, navigation, wp-debug

I'm using this function I found from this answer here about [showing prev/next navigation for a current page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54474/33243)

```
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent."&parent=".$post->post_parent."&sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc");
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search($post->ID, $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>
```

and I get an Undefined offset: 2  error with wp-debug set to true.

Could anyone help please- sorry I am a bit of a beginner with some of this, but I think it refers to the last 2 lines with $prevID and $nextID.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have those notices, if either of those `$pages` indexes are not set. Check for the existence of the key before trying to use it.

```
if (isset($pages[$current-1])) $prevID = $pages[$current-1];
if (isset($pages[$current+1])) $nextID = $pages[$current+1];
```

Or something along these lines ...

```
$prevID = (isset($pages[$current-1])) ? $pages[$current-1] : '';
$nextID = (isset($pages[$current+1])) ? $pages[$current+1] : '';
```

... so that you don't have other notices later when you try to use those variables.