# Next Previous siblings child pages

Tags: previous, next

I tried this piece of code : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54474/80921 because I couldn't figure out how to get the next and the previous post. But this code won't work now and I'm not able to comment.

The error I get is "Undefined offset: -1" when looking for the ID.
Here is the full code found on the related page. Thanks for any help !

```
$pagelist = get_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent."&parent=".$post->post_parent."&sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc");
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search($post->ID, $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>

<div class="navigation">
<?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
<div class="previous">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous</a>

</div>
<?php }
if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<div class="Next">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```